# Using GmailSender to send email without user interaction

Tags: android, email, gmail, send, interaction

I am using GMailSender class to send email without user interaction. Code is perfectly correct, it works on my Droid 3, but I just got a Samsung Galaxy S3, and it does not work. The code executes all the way up to the last statement in the try block but does not actually send the email!

So for example here the finished() method I created executes but the email never sends:

```
try
{
GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("someemail@gmail.com",   
                 "somepassword");
sender.sendMail(sub, mess, "someemail@gmail.com",     
"someotheremail@gmail.com");
finished();

}
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You should post some of the relevant code and log messages. What you posted isn't enough to determine the actual issue.

Comment: I'v edited it accordingly. Hope that helps sorry

Comment: Do you get any error messages in Logcat?

Comment: Nope, very strange being that it works on such an older model phone

Comment: another forum said it was a compatibility issue, any way around it maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, and the issue was wit my Gmail security, I had to activate "access from less secure apps" in Gmail options https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps and then it worked fine.

Remember also to allow Internet permission to the Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```